# Let $M\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},|k|>M} \frac1{(z-k)^2}$ converges uniformally on $B(0,M)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $M\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},|k|>M}
>  \frac1{(z-k)^2}$$ converges uniformally on $B(0,M)$

My attempt:

- $$\frac1{|(z-k)^2|} = \frac1{(x-k)^2+y^2}\le \frac1{y^2}.$$
- $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},|k|>M}\frac1{y^2} \text{ converges}.$$

M-test $\Rightarrow$ the given sum converges uniformally.

Is this approach correct? Does this imply that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}}
 \frac1{(z-k)^2}$ converges uniformally on $B(0,M)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How could $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z},|k|>M}\frac1{y^2}$ converge? You're just adding $1/y^2$ over and over!

Try this: For $z\in B(0,M)$ and $k>M,$ $|z-k| \ge k-M.$ Thus

$$\frac{1}{|z-k|^2}\le \frac{1}{(k-M)^2} .$$

Verify that $\sum_{k>M}\frac{1}{(k-M)^2}<\infty.$ Thus by Weierstrass M, $\sum_{k>M} \frac{1}{(k-z)^2}$ converges uniformly on $B(0,M).$ Same thing for $k<-M.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation! Now, for my second question, we can choose $ M=0$, which will imply that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z} \backslash\{0\}} \frac1{(z-k)^2}$ converges uniformly on $ B(0,0)=\{0\}$. For all $ M>0$, it is clearly true. So, the answer would be 'yes'?

Comment: Actually $B(0,0)$ is empty. But yes, that series converges for $z=0.$